# Are there any scriptures which say man is distraction for woman?

Tags: scripture

I heard that for a spiritual aspirant who is a male, women are considered a great distraction. Are there any scriptures/verses which say opposite i.e for woman, man is considered distraction?

Answer (score 3):

Yes here are couple of verses from Bhagavata Purana which says man is Maya for woman.

> SB 3.31.41 — A living entity who, as a result of attachment to a woman
>   in his previous life, has been endowed with the form of a woman,
>   foolishly looks upon **māyā in the form of a man, her husband**, as
>   the bestower of wealth, progeny, house and other material assets.
>
> SB 3.31.42 — **A woman, therefore, should consider her husband, her
>   house and her children to be the arrangement of the external energy of
>   the Lord for her death, just as the sweet singing of the hunter is
>   death for the deer**.

Comment: These 2 may be later insertion in SB to make it compatible with Sankara bhasya @KrishnaVarna we have shtri getting moksha so basically it contradicts Sruthi and other purana

Answer (score 1):

### Yes, the *Manusmriti* says women are easily aroused by looking at men.

In the [section](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/manusmriti-with-the-commentary-of-medhatithi/d/doc201363.html) in the *Manusmriti* on the ways for a husband to prevent adultery by the wife, some verses are given:

> 9.5 - Women should be specially guarded against even small attachments; for, if not guarded, they would bring grief to both
>   families.

Medhatithi's commentary for the verse:

> ‘Attachment’— association, with a woman of unknown character,—one who
>   is in the habit of standing at the doorway, looking at gaily dressed
>   young men passing by, and so forth.
>
> The meaning is that they should be guarded against temptations. Even
>   though the acts mentioned above,—i,e. gazing at young men and so forth
>   are not wrong in themselves, nor is the association of women with
>   women wrong in itself.

Another verse:

> 9.14 - They [women] care not for beauty; they have no regard for age; be he
>   handsome or ugly, they enjoy the man simply because he is a male.

The meaning of it is that women can commit adultery with another man, even if that man is not that handsome.

Medhatithi's commentary:

> The husband should not labour under the vain hope—‘I am well favoured,
>   handsome and young, how can my wife desire any other man, having
>   me?’;—because women do not take into consideration the fact of a man
>   being ‘handsome’ or ‘brave’; simply because he happens to be a male,
>   they have recourse to him.

Then:

> 9.15 - Even though carefully guarded, they injure their husbands, on account of their passion for males, of ficklemindedness and of innate
>   want of tenderness.

Medhatithi's commentary:

> ‘Passion for males’—**At the sight of any and every man, women lose
>   their firmness of mind and there arises in their minds an extreme
>   desire for meeting him somehow or other, followed by a liquid
>   exudation; this is what is called ‘passion for males.**’

And finally:

> 9.16 - Knowing this disposition to be innate in them, from the very creation
>   of the lord, the man should make the highest effort to guard them.